# Clojure macros: quoting, unquoting and evaluation

Tags: clojure, macros, quoting

I have the following code:

```
(ns macroo)

(def primitives #{::byte ::short ::int})

(defn primitive? [type]
  (contains? primitives type))

(def pp clojure.pprint/pprint)

(defn foo [buffer data schema]
  (println schema))

(defmacro write-fn [buffer schema schemas]
  (let [data (gensym)]
    `(fn [~data]
       ~(cond
          (primitive? schema) `(foo ~buffer ~data ~schema)
          (vector? schema) (if (= ::some (first schema))
                             `(do (foo ~buffer (count ~data) ::short)
                                 (map #((write-fn ~buffer ~(second schema) ~schemas) %)
                                       ~data))
                             `(do ~@(for [[i s] (map-indexed vector schema)]
                                      ((write-fn buffer s schemas) `(get ~data ~i)))))
          :else [schema `(primitive? ~schema) (primitive? schema)])))) ; for debugging

(pp (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(write-fn 0 [::int ::int] 0)))
```

The problem is, upon evaluating the last expression, I get

```
=>
(fn*
 ([G__6506]
  (do
   [:macroo/int :macroo/int true false]
   [:macroo/int :macroo/int true false])))
```

I'll explain the code if necessary, but for now i'll just state the problem (it might be just a newbie error I'm making):

```
`(primitive? ~schema)
```

and

```
(primitive? schema)
```

in the :else branch return true and false respectively, and since i'm using the second version in the cond expression, it fails where it shouldn't (I'd prefer the second version as it would be evaluated at compile time if i'm not mistaken).

I suspect it might have something to do with symbols being namespace qualified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigations (see edits), here is a working Clojure alternative. Basically, you rarely need recursive macros. If you
need to build forms recursively, delegate to auxiliary functions and call them from the macro (also, `write-fn` is not a good name).

```clj
(defmacro write-fn [buffer schemas fun]
  ;; we will evaluate "buffer" and "fun" only once
  ;; and we need gensym for intermediate variables.
  (let [fsym (gensym)
        bsym (gensym)]

    ;; define two mutually recursive function
    ;; to parse and build a map consisting of two keys
    ;;
    ;; - args is the argument list of the generated function
    ;; - body is a list of generated forms 
    ;;
    (letfn [(transformer [schema]
              (cond
                (primitive? schema)
                (let [g (gensym)]
                  {:args g
                   :body `(~fsym ~schema ~bsym ~g)})

                (sequential? schema)
                (if (and(= (count schema) 2)
                        (= (first schema) ::some)
                        (primitive? (second schema)))
                  (let [g (gensym)]
                    {:args ['& g]
                     :body
                     `(doseq [i# ~g]
                        (~fsym ~(second schema) ~bsym i#))})
                  (reduce reducer {:args [] :body []} schema))
                :else (throw (Exception. "Bad input"))))

            (reducer [{:keys [args body]} schema]
              (let [{arg :args code :body} (transformer schema)]
                {:args (conj args arg)
                 :body (conj body code)}))]

      (let [{:keys [args body]} (transformer schemas)]
        `(let [~fsym ~fun
               ~bsym ~buffer]
           (fn [~args] ~@body))))))
```

The macro takes a *buffer* (whatever it is), a schema as defined by your language and a function to be called for each value being visited by the generated function.

### Example

```clj
(pp (macroexpand
      '(write-fn 0 
                 [::int [::some ::short] [::int ::short ::int]] 
                 (fn [& more] (apply println more)))))
```

... produces the following:

```clj
(let*
 [G__1178 (fn [& more] (apply println more)) G__1179 0]
 (clojure.core/fn
  [[G__1180 [& G__1181] [G__1182 G__1183 G__1184]]]
  (G__1178 :macroo/int G__1179 G__1180)
  (clojure.core/doseq
   [i__1110__auto__ G__1181]
   (G__1178 :macroo/short G__1179 i__1110__auto__))
  [(G__1178 :macroo/int G__1179 G__1182)
   (G__1178 :macroo/short G__1179 G__1183)
   (G__1178 :macroo/int G__1179 G__1184)]))
```

- First, evaluate *buffer* and *fun* and bind them to local variables
- Return a closure which accept *one* argument and destructures it according to the given schema, thanks to Clojure's destructuring capabilities.
- For each value, call *fun* with the appropriate arguments.
- When the schema is `[::some x]`, accept zero or more values as a vector and call the function *fun* for each of those values. This needs to be done with a loop, since the size is only know when calling the function.

If we pass the vector `[32 [1 3 4 5 6 7] [2 55 1]]` to the function generated by the above macroexpansion, the following is printed:

```clj
:macroo/int 0 32
:macroo/short 0 1
:macroo/short 0 3
:macroo/short 0 4
:macroo/short 0 5
:macroo/short 0 6
:macroo/short 0 7
:macroo/int 0 2
:macroo/short 0 55
:macroo/int 0 1
```

Comment: The purpose of the function would be: for a given "schema", make a function that takes a datastructure - which is described by the schema - and converts it into bytes. The goal would be to create this function at compile-time and make it as dense as possible by inlining function arguments. So - optimally - the macroexpanded function wouldn't contain lists like ((fn [x] x) y).

Comment: @ViktorM. I edited the answer (I'll eventually clean up everything, but for now I'm trying to see what is the actual problem)

Comment: Although I can't really grok CL code (never fiddled with it), from what I can understand it certainly looks promising. That destructuring thingy is something I haven't explored. About the ::some case: [::some ::int] basically means that the datastructure contains some ints, whose count isn't known at compile time (it's some custom DSL I've defined for myself).

Comment: About your last edit: your code looks beautiful, although it will take some time to digest! I'll get back to you if I have further questions (I hope you don't mind).

Comment: There is a slight problem: '::some' can be followed by any valid schema, not just primitives. I fear this might be something that destructuring alone can't handle. I'll investigate what can be done, and post a followup question if I can't solve it.

Comment: This is a little more complex, but you need to have a destructuring `let` inside the body of the loop to get the components of `i`. This looks like a fun exercise :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
`(do ~@(for [[i s] (map-indexed vector schema)]
         ((write-fn buffer s schemas) `(get ~data ~i)))))
```

you are calling `write-fn`, the *macro*, in your current scope, where `s` is just a symbol, not one of the entries in `schema`. Instead, you want to emit code that will run in the caller's scope:

```
`(do ~@(for [[i s] (map-indexed vector schema)]
         `((write-fn ~buffer ~s ~schemas) (get ~data ~i)))))
```

And make a similar change to the other branch of the `if`, as well.

As an aside, it looks to me at first glance like this doesn't really need to be a macro, but could be a higher-order function instead: take in a schema or whatever, and return a function of data. My guess is you're doing it as a macro for performance, in which case I would counsel you to try it out the slow, easy way first; once you have that working you can make it a macro if necessary. Or, maybe I'm wrong and there's something in here that fundamentally has to be a macro.

Comment: I've already tried your suggestion - it works fine, but the macroexpanded form is full of expressions like ((fn [x] x) y), and I worry this will affect performance. What I tried to do is reduce those aforementioned lists to y-s (I've looked up definline and the :inline metadata, but I don't know if those are related to my problem). As for it being a macro or not: I've only recently dived into the world of macros, so it may be the case that a function would suffice.

Comment: Well, you can't really address the issue with "silly" macroexpansions this way: by omitting the syntax-quote you completely change the meaning of the expression, and it becomes basically nonsense. If you have a working version of your function that does the right thing, use it: if, after timing it, you find that it's too slow, ask another question about how to address your silly macroexpansions.

Comment: When you say "silly": do you mean that it's a failure on my part, or it's just something that clojure does I have to live with?

Comment: I mean that your macro has expanded to code that you personally consider silly: `((fn [x] x) y)` instead of `y`. Whether that is your fault or clojure's (it's not clojure's) isn't really relevant to my point, which is that until you have evidence that this is an actual problem for you rather than just silly, you may as well use the code you've written that already works. If you decide that's insufficient, for whatever reason, you should ask for help with improving the already-correct generated code, rather than presenting some broken code and saying "how do I make this correct".

Comment: About your last half-sentence: I do believe I made it clear that I'm not well-versed in this topic and I was ready to specify anything related to my code and motives (and yes, I did my study beforehand). Forgetting that, I appreciate your feedback and thank you for setting me on the right track. Have a nice day!